# :vsplit does nothing, sometimes

Tags: split, linux

In a specific context, typing `:vsplit` does nothing.

Typing `:split` still splits the screen horizontally. And if I open a new file e.g. `vi foo.txt` then `:vsplit` works.

**EDIT: steps to reproduce**

1. Type `/bin/vi` on the command-line
2. Type `:vsplit`. For me, nothing happens.

(See answer below for more)

**Context:**

I am running this script:

```
> cat fix.sh
I=0
for D in 2*; do
  vi ${D}/node_*;
  cp ${D}/node_input.txt samples.txt${I}
  cat ${D}/node_output.txt >> futen_output.txt
  I=$((${I} + 1))
done
```

On this machine:

```
> uname -a
Linux h3.karst.uits.iu.edu 2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 21 12:19:18 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In case it helps, here's my `.vimrc`:

```
set ai
set background=dark
set expandtab
set list
set listchars=trail:.
set nowrap
set nu
set ruler
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set nohlsearch
syntax on
```

**EDIT: more details about `/bin/vi`**

After typing `/bin/vi`, then typing `:version`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 12 2016 09:48:07)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-629
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             -cmdline_compl   -diff            -find_in_path    -keymap          -modify_fname    +multi_byte      -python3         -statusline      -title           -wildmenu
-arabic          +cmdline_hist    -digraphs        -float           -langmap         -mouse           -multi_lang      -quickfix        -sun_workshop    -toolbar         +windows
-autocmd         -cmdline_info    -dnd             -folding         -libcall         -mouse_dec       -mzscheme        -reltime         -syntax          -user_commands   +writebackup
-balloon_eval    -comments        -ebcdic          -footer          -linebreak       -mouse_gpm       -netbeans_intg   -rightleft       -tag_binary      -vertsplit       -X11
-browse          -conceal         -emacs_tags      +fork()          -lispindent      -mouse_jsbterm   -path_extra      -ruby            -tag_old_static  -virtualedit     -xfontset
+builtin_terms   -cryptv          -eval            -gettext         -listcmds        -mouse_netterm   -perl            -scrollbind      -tag_any_white   +visual          -xim
-byte_offset     -cscope          -ex_extra        -hangul_input    -localmap        -mouse_sgr       -persistent_undo -signs           -tcl             -visualextra     -xsmp
-cindent         -cursorbind      -extra_search    +iconv           -lua             -mouse_sysmouse  -printer         -smartindent     +terminfo        -viminfo         -xterm_clipboard
-clientserver    -cursorshape     -farsi           -insert_expand   -menu            -mouse_urxvt     -profile         -sniff           -termresponse    -vreplace        -xterm_save
-clipboard       -dialog          -file_in_path    +jumplist        -mksession       -mouse_xterm     -python          -startuptime     -textobjects     +wildignore      -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/virc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -U_FORTI
FY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm  -lselinux -ltinfo -lacl -lattr
```

After typing `/bin/vi`, then `:vsplit`, then `:messages`:

```
Messages maintainer: Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
```

Comment: To be running on Linux 2.6.32 that must be quite an old version of Vim. But moreover, since it is such an old Linux and on a university, it is likely to be heavily customized.  Therefore (1) check if this does happen when starting with `vim -u NONE --noplugin` and (2) have a look for customised scripts in the list printed by `:scriptnames`

Comment: @grochmal it seems to be RHEL 6 (or derivatives) form the `el6` in the version string, and RHEL 6.8 has Vim 7.4 (patches 1-207,209-629), so not very old. (That's newer than Ubuntu 14.04's 7.4, patches 1-52.)

Comment: your question is confusing. `:split` always splits horizontally, and `:vsplit` vertically. I am not sure I understand what exactly your problem is. Please give precise steps in Vim that reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. @grochmal (1) VIM 7.4.629 (2) `:scriptnames` prints nothing. @ChristianBrabandt my problem is that I type ":vsplit" and nothing happens. It does not split the screen vertically. Adding steps to reproduce above.

Comment: Please show the complete `:version` output. Doing nothing without any warning or error message is not very likely, so please check `:messages` for error messages

Comment: `-vertsplit` -- that version of Vim has been compiled without that feature.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line in my script that calls `vi`

```
  vi ${D}/node_*;
```

"`vi`" points to `/bin/vi`, and for some reason `/bin/vi` ignores the 
`:vsplit` command. I'll email the local sysadmin.

EDIT: @Antony points out, `/bin/vi` was compiled without the `vertsplit` option.

The fix is easy, change `vi` to `vim`.

Comment: Vi is acually Vim run in compability mode, the original editor Vi didn't have vsplit. That's why vsplit don't work